# How to recreate this lotus notes budget view?

Tags: view, lotus-notes

I've got a task to convert this lotus notes budget database to sharepoint. It has the below view and I have trouble understanding how to accomplish something similar in sharepoint. I have tried to 'group by' but that gives me two levels and as you see there are like 5 levels. I'm thinking about having a menu on the left side with links to the different sections using 'group by', but it would leave me with a great number of links and not be as smooth as the current database where you just 'unfold' the data lotus notes style. Does anyone have an idea to point me in the right direction?

[image: The budget in lotus notes]

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

So you want 4 grouping levels, and the plan is to create another column each year? is this data actually going to be entered into a SharePoint list? Or does the data come from a database? If the latter, then look , into using a reporting tool like SSRS, which can easily create the view as required. Or, if you're in SharePoint online, check into Power BI, which can't quite create that view, but it can come pretty close.

Or, write custom JavaScript code with jslink (this is not a beginner task). Or if you're in SharePoint online, this can also be done with the new SharePoint framework (very definitely not a beginner task).

Comment: +1 , SharePoint can only do 2 grouped levels and can't calculate cross-row. So time wise you might as well start from scratch. The new SharePoint Framework won't help either; that is only scaffolding for building Client Side Applications.. but you still have to buil the Application from scratch yourself.